# How to specify non-standard Python interpreter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My application has built-in Python interpreter and I need to debug Python code there. However Visual Studio Code allows to choose only from interpreters found in paths and named python/python2/python3.

I tried to set python.pythonPath in settings.json to point to my application, but Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize it as valid Python interpreter.

Sure, I need to make sure that my application behave like Python interpreter and pass all command-line parameters to Python ptvsd_launcher.py.

Comment: How did you acquire this additional Python interpreter? Did you install it from somewhere? What does VSCode say about it?

Answer (score 1):

The `"python.pythonPath"` setting is how you can specify a Python interpreter that is not automatically detected. If the binary does not function as a normal `python` binary then unfortunately there's no way for the extension to use it.

Comment: But what is expected from Python? My program has own header text, but internally it should accept Python script as command line argument and then execute it with built-in interpreter.

Comment: @EugeneZelenko Basically it needs to support `-c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"` and be able to run `pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py` in order to find out interpreter details that are needed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications! My program could execute second command but not first because it doesn't support -c and this should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you a lot for information! I added wrapper for my program to handle -c and also to remove boilerplate and it works fine with Visual Studio Code. I think will be good idea to add requirements for Python interpreter in documentation, so other programs with built-in Python could easily benefit debugging with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @EugeneZelenko Doc change suggestions should be made at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs, although in our release that went out yesterday this should be more obvious now and so it might not require specific documentation.

Comment: Was Python detection protocol changed since August 2019? I'm trying 1.42 and it looks from verbose output like Visual Studio Code also executes `-c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"` and `-m site --user-site`. I added later case in my application wrapper, but it's still not recognized as valid Python executable.

Comment: @EugeneZelenko it probably has changed as August 2019 was six months ago and we're still changing things in the extension.  We basically don't have good support for custom interpreter setups, so your best bet is opening a feature request for us to change the code so extraneous output is ignored somehow.

Comment: Hi, Brett! Thank you for clarification! I still think that best solution would be to document commands expected to work from application by extension. I tried to find out this with VS Code verbose output but unsuccessfully :-(